# 3D Texture mapping for sofa Simulator

Tags: php, jquery, html, 3d, graphic

This is a sample applicacion for a sofa simulator where different fabrics can be applied over the sofa body.

http://www.fama.es/virtual-simulator.html
 - To test it : click "Go to virtual simulator" - choose sofa model - apply a fabric to the sofa

How this kind of applicaction is done? what kind of technology should be used to be used on a web application?

Thanks

Comment: It is done via javascript. Seems, that they have layers with different fabrics and show them onmouseover. Take a look at `enciende` function in their code.

Comment: @user4035 thanks,But How do you think it apply fabrics to the sofa even in the edge .It's like a 3d map of the sofa .Do you how it's done?

Comment: @user4035 I couldn't find the function you mentioned.I want to know how do they apply the pattern so perfectly.

Comment: function enciende(codpatron) is located on this page: http://213.27.212.57/fama/escena_deco3d2.asp?u=549043532&n=NoIpad&d=0&contenedor_widthauto=

Comment: @user4035 after lot's of scrutiny I find out that it send the pattern to a page called escena_deco3d2.asp with parameters in url and make the pattern.That's the part I needed to know which is how to apply pattern in sofa.